# Edit Task Sequence XML using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm new to using PowerShell beyond my basic command line experience and have very little experience with actual scripting beyond basic batch files.

I'm having trouble with figuring out how to use a "loop" of some sort to add a value into an XML file.

Using guidance from a YouTube video (Reading and Updating XML Files) I was able to finally add the Application GUID to an XML file using PowerShell. This is what works:

```
$xmlFilePath = 'C:\Users\Timetriad\Desktop\1PASSWORD-7\ts.xml'
$tsXML = [xml] (Get-Content $xmlFilePath)
$tsXML.sequence.step.defaultVarList.variable[1].'#text' = '{f98806dd-02a4-4863-9b3e-fc83afd9d1e0}'  
$tsXML.Save($xmlFilePath)
```

Line 1 just sets the xml file path that I need to add the GUID to
Line 2 is needed to use the PowerShell xml tools
Line 3 is the path in the xml file where I need to add the GUID
Line 4 saves the changes back to the same xml file.

### My problem

I'm trying to figure out how I could loop my four lines of code above "WHAT WORKS" so I can read the "TS_ID" in the CSV file and then add the "GUID" to the corresponding ts.xml file. One thing to note is that the TS_ID is the name of the folder that holds the ts.xml file that I would like to add the GUID to.

My CSV file has only two two pieces of data: **TS_ID**, **GUID**

I'm excited that I can finally add the GUID to the ts.xml, but not looping it makes it more difficult than using the GUI to perform the same task in the application itself.

### Update

I added a comment that shows the XML data. It looks ugly, so I'm adding it here to my original post:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sequence version="3.00" name="Custom Task Sequence" description="Sample Custom Task Sequence">
  <step type="BDD_InstallApplication" name="Install Application" description="" disable="false" continueOnError="false" runIn="WinPEandFullOS" successCodeList="0 3010">
    <defaultVarList>
      <variable name="ApplicationGUID" property="ApplicationGUID"></variable>
      <variable name="ApplicationSuccessCodes" property="ApplicationSuccessCodes">0 3010</variable>
    </defaultVarList>
    <action>cscript.exe "%SCRIPTROOT%\ZTIApplications.wsf"</action>
  </step>
</sequence>
```

## Test provided by Cbsch with my edits:

```
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Control\TaskSequence-AppGUID-MDT.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ","
$csvData | ForEach-Object {
    $tsId = $_.TS_ID
    $guid = $_.GUID

    $xmlFilePath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Control\$tsId\ts.xml"
    $tsXML = [xml] (Get-Content $xmlFilePath)
    $tsXML.sequence.step.defaultVarList.variable[1].'#text' = "{$guid}"
    $tsXML.Save($xmlFilePath)
}
```

Final update using the expert help of "Cbsch".

Here are the final results that worked for my needs:

```
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Control\TaskSequence-AppGUID-MDT.csv"
$csvData | ForEach-Object {
    $tsId = $_.TS_ID
    $guid = $_.GUID

    $xmlPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Control\$tsId\ts.xml"
    $tsXML = [xml] (Get-Content $xmlPath)
    $tsXML.sequence.step.defaultVarList.variable[0].InnerText='#text';
    $tsXML.sequence.step.defaultVarList.variable[0]."#text" = "$guid"
    $tsXML.Save($xmlPath)
}
```

Note I'm not using the {} for my GUID variable because my CSV has them in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to read the CSV file into a variable. The `Import-Csv` will create an array of objects with property names matching the first line in the CSV file. Make sure you adjust the parameters on the `Import-Csv` command to match the file. Also after the `Import-Csv` command, you can do `$csvData | Out-Host` to make sure the data looks right.

Then we pipe the array into `ForEach-Object`. Inside the ScriptBlock passed to the `ForEach-Object` command the current object will be assigned to the variable `$_`. To make things a little more readable I then assign the properties from the object to their own variables.

Take note that to replace variables into strings you must use `""` and not `''`. I'm not sure which number is replaced in the path to your XML file, but you get the idea.

```bsh
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path "path\to\csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";"

$csvData | ForEach-Object {
    $tsId = $_.TS_ID
    $guid = $_.GUID

    $xmlFilePath = "C:\Users\Timetriad\Desktop\1PASSWORD-$tsId\ts.xml"
    $tsXML = [xml] (Get-Content $xmlFilePath)
    $tsXML.sequence.step.defaultVarList.variable[0].InnerText = "{$guid}"
    $tsXML.Save($xmlFilePath)
}
```

Comment: Cbsch, thank you so much for your help with this. It works, but for some reason it's adding the GUID to the wrong place; I'm not sure why, because there is no difference in the code to edit the xml file that I provided and what you used in the LOOP. The strange thing is that it's replacing the "ApplicationSuccessCode" in the 2nd "variable" instead of adding the GUID to the 1st VARIABLE text property that doesn't exist yet; which is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm wondering if I'm missing something. I added the xml code in post for reference.

Comment: Do I need to add a line to ADD the TEXT element in the 1st VARIABLE before I can add the GUID to that element? I tried changing the [1] to [0], but I get an error saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: Adding to the `0` element is the right thing. And you're right, you can't add to `'#text'` because it doesn't exist. But if you do this it will work `$xml.sequence.step.defaultVarList.variable[0].InnerText = "{$guid}"`

Comment: Cbsch.... You are the man! And you are not going to believe that I literally just accidentally stumbled onto this solution by experimenting with understanding this piece by piece. Pure luck on my end, but when I saw your solution, I was confident it would work... and IT DID!!!  I give you full credit for this and thank you so much. I've been wanting to do this for months but just kept putting it off because I just use my WDS/MDT for personal use.  I'm going to update my original post with the complete code you offered with my personal edits asking others to mark your response as the ANSWER.